# Azure cache billing when cache use is 0%

Tags: azure

I've an Bizspark account in Windows Azure.
At the moment I've configurated the namespaces to compute, storage, cache (and access control).
I've a simple Hello world extra-small compute to fill the domain.

The cache is empty but in Summary for Windows Azure account it's say that use 10% of cahce included in subscription.

My question is, it's per day, and when rich the last day is at 100%, or is another thing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the trial account or something similar, then you are given a cache, normally 128MB for the month.

However they charge you on a daily rate. If you were paying for it, it would be $45/30 = $1.50.

It doesn't matter how much of the cache you use. It is based on a flat rate.

Comment: I suspect its that situation. Thank you for the confirmation! :)